# awk search line for bracket e.g [

Tags: bash, awk

So I need to parse a file and am only interested in the lines that start with "[" 
for example the line below.

`[139.797570.657062] 64 bytes from cache.google.com (143.215.192.243): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=3.61 ms`

I have a file containing many of these lines in a row and i want a new file containing just these lines. Im going through a bash loop and cant get awk to search for the bracket because its a keyword or what ever. this is what I have so far.

```
while read p; do

echo $p | awk '/[/'

 done < temp.txt
```

`temp.txt` being the file containing the lines I'm interested in

this wold work with a word like "the" instead of "[" but I want to be able to search for the bracket with awk. I hope that is clear enough, thanks for reading.

Comment: If you're just searching like this, you'd be better off with grep - `grep '\[' <<<$p`.

Comment: The point of it was to learn awk. Thats why I didnt use grep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '/\[/' temp.txt > out.txt
```

The `[` must be escaped as `\[`; also, if your lines all *start* with `[`, it's better to use `/^\[/`.

No need for a `while` loop - awk will read the whole file line by line.

Comment: @user3371963 You can thank him by accepting the answer. You can do so by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Oh and BTW welcome to Stack Overflow.